# log4j2 with vertx 4.4.2

Tags: maven, vert.x

I added log4j2 to my pom.xml like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The linter shows me that `Dependency conflict in log4j-core: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1 conflict with 2.20.0`

I cannot find where is 2.17.1 defined.

If I start the server I get `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...`

How can i resolve this maven conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `mvn  dependency:tree` somehow shows `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.20.0:test`, so I put `<scope>compile</scope>` at the log4j2 section, and now I get no error message.